# A better way than if/else to check index array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am geting an index out of bounds error, I understand why I am getting it.  What I am looking for is perhaps some features of c# I may not be aware of instead of using a bulky if/else statement.

If the Active Directory user does not have a job title this errors out because it will not load the property so rs.Propterties["title"] doesn't even exist to my knowledge.

Is there a cleaner way to do it than if (rs.Properties["title"].Count)

```
user.jobTitle = rs.Properties["title"][0].ToString();
```

I was looking into different operators like ?? and ?: but couldn't figure out how to get them to work properly.

rs.Properties is of type SearchResult from:

using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

Comment: @PrestonGuillot rs is a SearchResult type.  from the DirectoryServices.

Comment: Properties is typeof Dic<string, list> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
user.jobTitle = (rs.Properties["title"].FirstOrDefault() ?? "").ToString();
```

That's assuming `rs.Properties["title"]` is of type `IEnumerable<object>` or something similar. If it's just `IEnumerable`, you'd need something like:

```
user.jobTitle = (rs.Properties["title"]
                   .Cast<object>()
                   .FirstOrDefault() ?? "").ToString();
```

The [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358452.aspx) call will return null if the collection is empty.

(Now that we know the type of `rs`, it looks like the latter is required.)

You may want to wrap that into your own extension method, of course:

```
public static string GetFirstProperty(this SearchResult result,
                                      string propertyName,
                                      string defaultValue)
{
    return result.Properties[propertyName]
                 .Cast<object>()
                 .FirstOrDefault() ?? defaultValue).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

```
user.jobTitle = rs.Properties.Contains("Title") ? rs.Properties["Title"][0].ToString() : string.Empty;
```

**Option 2**

```
public static class SearchResultHelper
{
    public static string GetValue(this SearchResult searchResult, string propertyName)
    {
        return searchResult.Properties.Contains(propertyName) ? searchResult.Properties[propertyName][0].ToString() : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Call would look like

```
user.JobTitle = rs.Properties.GetValue("Title")
```

Thanks to http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/getuserfrmactdircsharp.aspx for AD example

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
user.jobTitle = rs.Properties["title"]
    .Cast<object>()
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .MaybePipe(x => x.ToString());
```

Helper function that I use everywhere:

```
public static TResult MaybePipe(this T obj, Func<T, TResult> func)
{
    return obj != null ? func(obj) : default(T);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the type which is a SearchResult type.  Which doesn't have the FirstOrDefault built in.  Anyone to still do it?

Comment: @JamesWilson What is the type of `Properties["title"]`?

Comment: It is SearchResult, updated the original post as well.  Jon Skeet was able to answer it similar to your suggestions.

Comment: @JamesWilson I added the `Cast<object>()` call which will turn your `IEnumerable` into `IEnumerable<object>`.